# C++ Segmentation when using erase on std::list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, erase

I'm trying to remove items from a C++ linked list using `erase` and a list iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

class Item
{
  public:
    Item() {}
    ~Item() {}
};

typedef std::list<Item> list_item_t;


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  // create a list and add items
  list_item_t newlist;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
  {
    Item temp;
    newlist.push_back(temp);
    std::cout << "added item #" << i << std::endl;
  }

  // delete some items
  int count = 0;
  list_item_t::iterator it;

  for ( it = newlist.begin(); count < 5 ; ++it )
  {
    std::cout << "round #" << count << std::endl;
    newlist.erase( it );
    ++count;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get this output and can't seem to trace the reason:

```
added item #0
added item #1
added item #2
added item #3
added item #4
added item #5
added item #6
added item #7
added item #8
added item #9
round #0
round #1
Segmentation fault
```

I'm probably doing it wrong, but would appreciate help anyway. thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The core problem here is you're using at iterator value, `it`, after you've called `erase` on it.  The `erase` method invalidates the iterator and hence continuing to use it results in bad behavior.  Instead you want to use the return of `erase` to get the next valid iterator after the erased value.

```
it = newList.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  it = newList.erase(it);
}
```

It also doesn't hurt to include a check for `newList.end()` to account for the case where there aren't at least 5 elements in the `list`.

```
it = newList.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 5 && it != newList.end(); i++) {
  it = newList.erase(it);
}
```

As [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108994/tim) pointed out, here's a great reference for `erase`

- [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Comment: Better answer than mine.  You don't want to combine it++ and erase, and this neatly sidesteps that.  But I do like sharing links to some of my favorite reference pages:  [list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/)

Comment: @Tim, added the reference to my answer.  It's my goto page as well for C++ STL questions.

Answer (score 3):

When you erase an element at position `it`, the iterator `it` gets invalidated - it points to a piece of memory that you just freed.

The `erase(it)` function returns another iterator pointing to the next element to the list. Use that one!

Answer (score 2):

You're invalidating your iterator when you `erase()` within the loop. It would be simpler to do something like this in place of your erase loop:

```
list_item_t::iterator endIter = newlist.begin();
std::advance(endIter, 5);
newList.erase(newlist.begin(), endIter);
```

You might also be interested in the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
for(list<type>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
{
     if(shouldErase)
     { 
        i = list.erase(i);
        i--;
     }
}
```

Edited because I'm a bonehead that can't read apparently lol.

Comment: There is no skipping problem with the accepted answer: the loop doesn't increment the iterator, **it**, but an integer counter, **i**.

Comment: o yeah, I missed them being different lol. stupid t. editing my answer

Comment: Though I don't see how the code in the answer would work either. Unless I'm an idiot again, it looks like the code would try to erase the beginning of the list, and then the next item, and the next item, until i gets to 5.

Comment: Because the question was about deleting the first 5 items of the list. But anyway, removing the `i++` from the loop statement and putting it as an else clause would be better.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better I think. The question was about fixing the seg fault though, not just removing the first five elements of the list. That just happened to be what he was trying to do.