# Iterators of map and list showing different behaviour

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator, segmentation-fault

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145634/c-segmentation-when-using-erase-on-stdlist) post on stack overflow and found out the way to delete elements in a list iteratively. I wanted to try the same with both `map` and `list`. I got a segmentation fault with `list` as expected but I did not get one with `map`. Why is it so??

Below are the codes for both.

Using list :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   list<int>l ;
   l.push_back(1);l.push_back(2);l.push_back(3);l.push_back(4);l.push_back(5);
   list<int>::iterator it;
   for(it = l.begin();it!=l.end();it++){
       l.erase(it);
       cout<<"Give me some output..\n";
   }
   return 0;
}

Output :

Give me some output..
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Using map :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   map<int, int>m ;
   m[1] = 1;m[2] = 2;m[3] = 3;m[4] = 4;
   map<int,int>::iterator it;
   for(it = m.begin();it!=m.end();it++){
       m.erase(it);
       cout<<"Give me some output..\n";
   }
   return 0;
}

Output :

Give me some output..
Give me some output..
Give me some output..
Give me some output..
```

Shouldn't list iterators and map iterators show the same behaviour ??

**ASIDE :**

The actual problem I was facing was I was using a map in a big program and trying to delete elements from it with the wrong method mentioned above and I got the segmentation fault. Then I visited the above mentioned link and resolved the issue.**But shouldn't both the codes give segmentation fault**. How can two codes using same snippet of code show different behaviours. Is it that one code is small, hence the compiler was able to correct that by itself??

Comment: Lack of segmentation fault is one of the possible observable effects of undefined behavior. Your question is like 'Laws say that theft is punishable with prison, but I just stole something an no one caught me. But my friend stole something else and she got caught and now she is serving time. How so?'

Comment: So, it means that we can get an output for `cout<<array[-1]<<endl;` with a probability > 0. Am I correct??

Comment: @2rd_7 it can do anything (literally)  see: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Comment: I doubt there is any event in the universe for which you can say that it's probability is 0.

Comment: @SergeyA There is probability 0 that I have 17 fingers.

Comment: It simply means that the C++ standard does not prescribe the behavior. The behavior is determined by other factors related to your particular implementation.

Comment: @Barry, this is not a question of probability theory for you. It is already a fact. You do have a certain number of fingers. However, the probability that someone I meet today has 17 fingers is not 0. (Even that for that person it is also not a probability, but a fact!) Probability theory is fun and paradoxical like that.

Comment: But think of how fast Barry could code with 17 fingers. That would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Both [`list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) and [`map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) state:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

When you subsequently call `it++` you are incrementing an invalid reference is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Fortunately this is a simple problem to solve as both containers' `erase`-methods return the next valid iterator, so if for some reason you didn't just want to call `clear` you could do:

```
for(auto it = cbegin(l); it != cend(l); it = l.erase(it)) cout << "Give me some output..\n";
```